# Appending to a instance (for a class list attribute)

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's the most Pythonic way to write the below append statement:

```
class MyClass():
    my_list = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.attr_a = 'whatever_a_is'
        # NOTE below is commented out here because it's
        # NOT needed by most instances:
        # self.my_list = []


my_class_instance= MyClass()
# Append 'a_certain_value' to list attribute if it exists
# else create it:
if my_class_instance.my_list:
    my_class_instance.my_list.append('a_certain_value')
else:
    my_class_instance.my_list = ['a_cetain_value']
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It would probably be best just to tuck that away into an `append` method of `MyClass` so the caller doesn't need to worry about it, or just make `my_list` an empty list from the start.

Comment: Tks. making it an empty list creates the pitfall of a mutable class attribute when using methods like append (it's being appended to all instances).  if it's when I __init__ of a new instance, please refer to my commented code in the __init__ function above. On the other hand, a custom-build append method is an option but I wanted to see if there's a simpler way to handle this in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

When the class is initialised, it sets `my_list = None`. It would be better to set `my_list = []`, so that the caller can simply append to the list without worrying if it exists or not. This is far more pythonic than what you currently have.

---

P.S.

A suggestion for future code to make it more "Pythonic" is to replace `if my_class_instance.my_list` with `if my_class_instance.my_list is not None` like so:

```
if my_class_instance.my_list is not None:
    my_class_instance.my_list.append("a_certain_value")
else:
    my_class_instance.my_list = ["a_certain_value"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If i get it write, you don't want to set `my_list` attribute at initialization but only at the first append use ?

A way to do it is to build a custom append method that do the job and are transparent for user :

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        # do something here
        pass

    def custom_append(self, a_certain_value):
        if hasattr(self, 'my_list'):
            self.my_list.append(a_certain_value)
        else:
            self.my_list = [a_certain_value]


my_class_instance = MyClass()

my_class_instance.custom_append('a_certain_value')
```

But there is few cases where you do not want to initiate `my_list` to an empty list at instance creation.

Comment: Tks. First option isn't helping me avoid the verbose if / else statement. Second is already in my code (please check commented stuff in __init__)

Comment: certainly works. But, as mentioned in my comment in the above post, would prefer a method from standard library if one exists.....

Comment: hasattr is a python built-in function. You can do the same job with a try/except statement in your custom methods. Anyay, idid not heard of a special append method that create the atribute if not exist

Comment: I was hoping there's something like setdefault for dicts